# How to download a dynamically generated file without blocking the page ?

Tags: 2010, web-part

In one of my webpart I have a feature to generate a file dynamically depending on what the users choosed in the view.

On my OnClick event handler, I have this code :

```
protected void reportClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MemoryStream ms = GenerateFile();

    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    byte[] byteArray = ms.ToArray();

    ms.Flush();
    ms.Close();

    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report.docx");
    Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", byteArray.Length.ToString());
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Context.Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
    Context.Response.End();
}
```

It works as the file is proposed to download to the user. The problem is that after the download, the page is blocked: the buttons are still clickable but there are no actions done on the click. I have to refresh the page to enable the actions again.

Is there a way to download a file without blocking the page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your webpart code you can do this by rendering a hyperlink to a SharePoint application page (under the  _layouts folder), rather than a button. The application page should contain the code to dynamically generate your file.

Comment: Another option will be using custom HTTP handler, as this is the mechanism dedicated to handle such a scenario in ASP.NET.

Comment: If I use another page, how do I pass information to this page from the first one to know what to generate ? Can I pass a MemoryStream to the other page or a List ?

Comment: How about using query string parameters?

Comment: Querystring would be best

Comment: The problem with QueryString is that I have to give it a list of IDs so I have to parse it to pass it to the URL and then parse it again to get the ID. But that's a good start, thanks.